# phone gap apps - How can i detect thet a login web service request is genuine

Tags: web-services, security, cordova, mobile

We r finally taking a leap into writing a mobile application for some of our platforms core functionality.

After spending some time - narrowed down that it is a HTML 5 application, CSS and Apache Phone gap to support different platforms mainly IOS and Android

We are writing WCF based REST services and have a question about securing the web service calls - specially ones for new user creation and login.

How can we ensure that the web service call to create a new user account or subsequently to log into the app is genuinely originating from a mobile device and not via a brute attack or someone trying to execute a service if they do discover the URL? Is there some kind of device identifier that we can depend on as part of the request (or something we embed into the app) etc or are there other more reliable techniques.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0):

Good question:  I use the [device plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1178) to get the device uuid and then hash it with the user email and the timestamp of the registration to create a key.  One way hashing is your friend in this scenario.  Keep all of your communication on https secure socket layer and create keys based on the UUID and you should be able to solve this problem.

Comment: So if i understand correctly - when a new user is created he send the device uuid over https - generate a unique hash - return it to the app. After that the hash is saved on the device? and used for subsequent logins and all web request?

Comment: That's one way of doing it.  When you couple it with a time stamp the key becomes good for the duration of the current install meaning that if the user destroys the key by re-installing the app you can force a re-authentication before enabling communication again.   Alternatively you can pass key elements including UUID, stored parameters such as user id etc on each communication and check them by hashing and comparing.  Either way the UUID allows you to id the device.